# understanding derivative of a vector function

Tags: calculus, vectors

If I have a vector function $r(t)$ , why is the tangent vector at t
$\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} (\frac{r(t+\Delta t)-r(t)}{\Delta t})$ and not just simply 
$\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} ({r(t+\Delta t)-r(t)})$..I understand that if we divide it by $\Delta t$ and further simplify it , we will get the derivative of the vector function as the derivative of its individual components but i dont understand why we do so..
[image]

Comment: By continuity, your definition equals zero.

Comment: If $r$ is at least continuous, then you would always have $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} (r(t+\Delta t) -r(t)) = 0$, so that this limit is not very interesting.

Comment: but why do we divide it only by $\Delta t$ and not anything else

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as calculating the velocity of the moving particle $r$ because the direction of its velocity is the same as the direction of the tangent line of its trajectory.

To calculate its velocity, we divide a certain distance that it passes through by the amount of time it takes to pass through that distance.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent at $t$ is the limit case of the secant:
$$
\lim_{t' \to t} \frac{r(t') - r(t)}{t' - t}
$$
or $t' = t + \Delta t$ thus
$$
\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{r(t+\Delta t) - r(t)}{t+\Delta t- t}
$$